# Angular push checkbox value to unique array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am using`ng-repeat` to display a number of exercises in the view. Each exercise has a number of parameters bound to checkboxes. The aim is to select the checkboxes and click save and this will create an array in the following structure as a child of the parent object - `exercise`:

```
    [{
        "name": "Sets",
        "checked": true
    }, {
        "name": "Reps",
        "checked": true
    }, {
        "name": "Weight",
        "checked": false
    }]
```

My current structure gives me the following which is difficult for me to use in my app:

```
{"Sets":true,"Weight":true}
```

These results are going to be saved to Parse.com so when they are retrieved the checkboxes should be bound and be automatically checked if the value is `true`.

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xLhExqNO9NoU7ltC2mAM?p=preview) to try and illustrate my issue.

The desired object to be saved to Parse.com is like this:

```
{
    "exerciseName": "Neutral Spine on Gym Ball ",
    "exerciseID": "1",
    "objectId": "TAwNkGHxoz",
    "images": [3, 4, 5],
    "tags": ["Gym Ball", "Static Control", "Lumbar ", "Thoracic Region", "Balance & Proprioception", "Core Control", "Abdominals", "Back"],
    "parameters": [{
        "name": "Sets",
        "checked": true
    }, {
        "name": "Reps",
        "checked": true
    }, {
        "name": "Weight",
        "checked": false
    }]
}
```